# How To Make Joi Warning On Non-Existant property

Tags: javascript, schema, joi

How can I use Joi to throw a WARNING but not an ERROR if a particular element does not exist?

My Code:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string()
        .alphanum()
        .min(3)
        .max(30)
        .required(),
    birth_year: Joi
        .number()
        .min(2000)
        .warn()
});

console.log({ error, warning, value } = schema.validate({ username: 'abc', birth_year: 1994 }));
console.log({ error, warning, value } = schema.validate({ username: 'abc'}));
```

I can successfully see a warning when the birth year does not have the minimum I require

> '"birth_year" must be greater than or equal to 2000'

however, I also want to WARN if birth year does not exist.

Currently I do not get a warning or an error. If I add `.required()` to the birth year schema it will ERROR if birth year does not exist. I have tried making this:

```
birth_year: Joi
        .number()
        .min(2000)
        .warn()
        .required()
        .warn()
```

however this generates a runtime error because .warn() terminates the schema options. I also tried moving .required to be the second option, but again it errors, not warns.

Comment: Ever solve this issue? Trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: hey @JonathanCorrin. I never did solve this issue, I had to roll my own separate custom checks for if the field exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Use warn() and validateAsync() method with warnings option to true:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
          username: Joi.string()
                    .alphanum()
                    .min(3)
                    .max(30)
                    .required(),
          birth_year: Joi
                      .number()
                      .min(2000)
                      .warn()     // warning
                      .required()
});
```

Now you can validate it with `validateAsync()` method in `async` function like this:

```
(async function(){
    try {
       const { value, warning } = await schema.validateAsync({ username: 'abc', birth_year: 1994 }, { warnings: true });
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

This code will throw error if birth_year field does not exist or warning if birth_year field exists but not as required.

Note that `warn()` will terminate the current ruleset and cannot be followed by another rule option. Use `rule()` to apply multiple rule options.

For more information: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anywarn

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, if you are adamant about issuing a warning, instead of an error:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-nuys5f?file=index.js

Essentially you would create another variable which would validate the variable you want to issue a warning for when it is not present.